# Problems to perform Get operation through Bosun Generic Enabler of FIWARE

Tags: fiware, fiware-bosun

I have Installed Bosun in a VM. It’s running but when I perform a GET operation to get the tenant information, I receive a “Timeout response. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are getting that error because you are behind a firewall.
If you are using a VM in the fi-lab, ensure your security group has 8000 and 5000 ports opened.

Otherwise, check your router to accept requests through these ports.